# Train a dog for shoulder carry

Tags: dogs, training

I was looking for advice/steps for training a dog for shoulder carry. I googled for someone to walk through the steps, but I didn't find anything. I think I understand the general steps, but I want to make sure that I don't miss something or cause our dog harm. At the bottom is a picture of what I'd like as my end goal. Thanks in advance!

[image: this is my end goal]

Comment: Are you able to confirm the breed or size of dog and approximate weight?

Comment: German Sheppard and approximately 85lbs

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on the actual steps for a safe shoulder carry specifically, but  a good place to start for any kind of carrying or actions like that is gaining full trust of the dog. When carrying them normally around they should not be trying to squirm around and jump out of your hands, they should be calm and trust in you. They should also feel secure, the picture looks like he's bracing the dogs back and chest and the dog looks like it's supporting itself using it's legs too. But maybe if the dog can't do this or is injure, get the dog comfortable with being held high up by you. If you got the technique of the carry down, my advice for the steps would be to build the trust your dog has in you, he should be totally comfortable in your arms. Once you have the trust part down try gradually trying out shoulder carrying, maybe starting out crouching low, then going to a full stride or something.

Comment: Thank you. I have been working on doing a fireman's carry with the dog. He seems to trust me but isn't quite comfortable yet so I am not moving around yet. I was just thinking ahead about transitioning to a shoulder carry and then being able to call him over my back to the shoulder carry position.

Comment: Definitely a good place to start, once you can get to the point where he's 100% comfortable in the fireman's carry I'd say you're set to move on